# Problemas con "Pluviometro" Hashmap, List... java.lang.StackOverflowError

Tags: java, lista, hashmap

Estoy muy pez en este tema y no se resolverlo. 
Me aparece el siguiente error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at Pluviometro.<init>(Pluviometro.java:11)
```

Programa:

```
public interface Meses {

    public static final String MES_ENERO = "ENERO";
    public static final String MES_FEBRERO = "FEBRERO";
    public static final String MES_MARZO = "MARZO";
    public static final String MES_ABRIL = "ABRIL";
    public static final String MES_MAYO = "MAYO";
    public static final String MES_JUNIO = "JUNIO";
    public static final String MES_JULIO = "JULIO";
    public static final String MES_AGOSTO = "AGOSTO";
    public static final String MES_SEPTIEMBRE = "SEPTIEMBRE";
    public static final String MES_OCTUBRE = "OCTUBRE";
    public static final String MES_NOVIEMBRE = "NOVIEMBRE";
    public static final String MES_DICIEMBRE = "DICIEMBRE";

}
```

Pluviometro:

```
public class Pluviometro implements Meses {

    private HashMap<String, Pluviometro> hm = new HashMap<String, Pluviometro>();
    ArrayList<Integer> pre = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    public Pluviometro() {
        hm.put(MES_ENERO, new Pluviometro());
        hm.put(MES_FEBRERO, new Pluviometro());
        hm.put(MES_MARZO, new Pluviometro());
        hm.put(MES_ABRIL, new Pluviometro());
        hm.put(MES_MAYO, new Pluviometro());
        hm.put(MES_JUNIO, new Pluviometro());
        hm.put(MES_JULIO, new Pluviometro());
        hm.put(MES_AGOSTO, new Pluviometro());
        hm.put(MES_SEPTIEMBRE, new Pluviometro());
        hm.put(MES_OCTUBRE, new Pluviometro());
        hm.put(MES_NOVIEMBRE, new Pluviometro());
        hm.put(MES_DICIEMBRE, new Pluviometro());
    }

    public void putPrecipitacion(String Meses, int litros) {
        pre.add(litros, Integer.parseInt(Meses));
    }

    public String getPre(String Meses) {
        String s = "";
        for(int i = 0; i < pre.size(); i++) {
            s = s + pre.get(i) + " ";
        }
        return s;
    }

    public int totalMes(String Meses) {
        int litros = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
            litros = litros + pre.get(i);
        }
        return litros;
    }

    public int mediaDiaria(String Meses) {
        return Math.round(totalMes(Meses)/30);
    }

    public int mediaMensual(String Meses) {
        return Math.round(totalAnual(Meses)/30);
    }

    public int totalAnual(String Meses) {
        int litros = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < 365; i++) {
            litros+=pre.get(i);
        }
        return litros;
    }

}
```

Main:

```
public class Actividad8 implements Meses {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {


        Pluviometro plv = new Pluviometro();

        //Insertar datos de forma aleatoria
        String[] meses = {MES_ENERO, MES_FEBRERO, MES_MARZO, MES_ABRIL, MES_MAYO, MES_JUNIO, MES_JULIO, MES_AGOSTO, MES_SEPTIEMBRE, MES_OCTUBRE, MES_NOVIEMBRE, MES_DICIEMBRE};
        int mes;
        int litros;
        for(int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
            mes = (Integer.valueOf(Double.toString(Math.random()).substring(2,4))%12);
            litros = Integer.valueOf(Double.toString(Math.random()).substring(2,4));
            plv.putPrecipitacion(meses[mes], litros);
        }

        //Visualización de los datos
        for(int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
            System.out.println(meses[i] + ": " + plv.getPre(meses[i])
                    + "    Total mensual: " + plv.totalMes(meses[i])
                    + "    Media diaria: " + plv.mediaDiaria(meses[i])
                    + "    Total anual: " + plv.totalAnual(meses[i])
                    + "    Media mensual: " + plv.mediaMensual(meses[i]));;
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Tienes un problema de recursividad infinita.

Si notas en tu constructor:

```
public Pluviometro() {
    hm.put(MES_ENERO, new Pluviometro());
    hm.put(MES_FEBRERO, new Pluviometro());
    hm.put(MES_MARZO, new Pluviometro());
    hm.put(MES_ABRIL, new Pluviometro());
    hm.put(MES_MAYO, new Pluviometro());
    hm.put(MES_JUNIO, new Pluviometro());
    hm.put(MES_JULIO, new Pluviometro());
    hm.put(MES_AGOSTO, new Pluviometro());
    hm.put(MES_SEPTIEMBRE, new Pluviometro());
    hm.put(MES_OCTUBRE, new Pluviometro());
    hm.put(MES_NOVIEMBRE, new Pluviometro());
    hm.put(MES_DICIEMBRE, new Pluviometro());
}
```

... el constructor de `Pluviometro` ejecuta el constructor de `Pluviometro` (`new Pluviometro()`), quien a su vez ejecuta el constructor de `Pluviometro`, etc... de forma infinita hasta que recibes el `StackOverflowException`.

Obviamente, se trata de un problema de diseño. Pero como no sé lo que estás tratando de hacer, no te puedo recomendar una solución concreta, si no que simplemente te dejo saber donde está el problema.